# File upload with SESSION array instead of $_FILES?

Tags: php, session, file-upload

The question is: Is there is any way to make it work with SESSION array ?

Because i have assigned $_FILES["file"] to a SESSION array, it would not upload a file. When i use var_dump($_SESSION['test'][1]["tmp_name"]) and var_dump($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]) it would show the same value. any idea guys ?

```
//THIS WONT WORK
    $_SESSION['file'][] = $_FILES["file"];
    $_SESSION['file'][] = $_FILES["file2"];
    foreach($_SESSION['file'] as $index => $name){
       move_uploaded_file($_SESSION['file'][$index]["tmp_name"], "images/" . $rename);
    }
//THIS WORKS OK
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    "images/" . $rename);
```

Ok now few words why i need to use session ... I need to use session because i have multiple files that i want to upload through foreach statement.

// print_r($_SESSION["file"]) would output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "face.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(31) "C:\EasyPHP-12.1\tmp\php882C.tmp"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(22398)
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: The question is: Is there is any way to make it work with SESSION array ?

Comment: No point setting and using a session value on the same page on the same load. Anyways add `session_start()` to the top

Comment: I have session_start() in my confing file on top of every page... this is not the reason. And there is a point of using session if you for example along with the images need to add all the keywords alt tags and so on. I have form forking with ajax submiting all this info with each file. Thats why i have session array

Comment: Why would anybody want to do this?

Comment: `print_r($_SESSION["file"]);`: What does it say?

Comment: array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "face.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(31) "C:\EasyPHP-12.1\tmp\php882C.tmp"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(22398)
  }
}

Comment: I think the problem you're having is that the tempoary upload files are automatically deleted when the script ends. So saving the name in `$_SESSION` won't help -- the file is gone.

Comment: If you're uploading multiple files with AJAX, each call will be independent, and the script can save that one file. Why do you need sessions for this?

Comment: Is there is any way of keeping the file the variable ?

Comment: I want to collect all file reference first to upload them at once on the end of the session.

Answer (score 2):

[Quote from the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of
>   the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.

You must `move_uploaded_file()` for each new file you add by the end of your AJAX script. If you don't want orphaned files to stick around, you could move them into a temporary directory before your form is submitted and clean up the directory at regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must save your file using move_uploaded file
2. Check whether `$_SESSION["test"]` exists. If not, create it, `$_SESSION["test"] = array();`
3. `$_SESSION["test"][] = "images/" . $rename;`
4. You can reach the last uploaded file with `$_SESSION["test"][count($_SESSION["test"] - 1]`. If you uploaded a single file, then it is incorrect to reference to it with `$_SESSION["test"][1]`.

Comment: yes this was only example in code i use move_uploaded_file($_SESSION['test'][$index]["tmp_name"] i use foreach to access the file from the session